# Exoplayer r1.5.2 failed to resolve com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, exoplayer

I have a problem when trying to `compile exoplayer r1.5.2 repository...`. There's no issue when I use `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.2` instead.

Here's of the compilation code:

[image]

And then this error is thrown:

[image]

Comment: It's weird, I just tied the 1.5.2 like you show here, and no problem with it. `compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'`

Comment: Did you click the "Install Repository and sync project"? Seems like you've just upgraded from 1.4.2 to 1.5.2, and haven't pulled down the latest.

Comment: @ChrisJ now it's working fine without any extra effort....i just restarted my pc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue as well: I added `compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'` to my `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
}
```

And tried `sync project` in Android Studio, but got the error above.

## Solution

I got the dependency downloaded by upgrading to gradle 2.6 and invoking gradle from the shell:

```
$ ./gradlew build
```

### Upgrading Gradle

Edit the `distributionUrl` line in  `<project dir>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip
```

Comment: $ ./gradlew build from terminal then try again install Repository and sync project worked perfectly. thanks.